# Creating a FlatList Grid from props data

Tags: react-native

Creating a screen that contains a FlatList grid of photos that I fetch from my rails API. Having trouble displaying the data - https://ibb.co/XkfSvxm. I wish for the images, regardless of how many there are, to be in a square format.

Currently, I can fetch and display the data in square photos except whenever there is 1 or 2 photos on a row. They fill the row rather than take the formatting from the `formatItems` method (which essentially pushes two empty items into the array forcing the data into a grid).

I've tried a bunch of things including returning the data straight from `formatItems` and plugging the method straight into the data of the flatlist, but then no data is loading. I also had it working well with a local SQL DB package.

How would I go around arranging so that I can format the data from props and display it correctly in the FlatList?

Here is the code:

```
class VaultScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
      searchQuery: '',
      refreshing: false,
      setRefreshing: false
    };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: {},
      itemSelected: {}
    };
    this.props.fetchPosts()
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let itemData = this.props.posts
    this.setState({
      items: itemData,
    });
    // this.formatItems(itemData)
  }

  formatItems = () => {
    const { items } = this.state
    const newItems = []
    const numberOfFullRows = Math.floor(items.length / 3);
    // const numberOfFullRows = Math.floor(itemData.length / 3);
    let numberOfElementsLastRow = 1
    // items.length - (numberOfFullRows * 3);

    while (numberOfElementsLastRow !== 3 && numberOfElementsLastRow !== 0) {
      newItems.push({ key: `blank-${numberOfElementsLastRow}`, empty: true });
      numberOfElementsLastRow++;
    }
    return this.setState({ items: newItems })
  };

  renderItem = ({ item, type }) => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    if (item.empty === true) {
      return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
  } else {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPressIn={() => this.setState({ itemSelected: item.id })} onPress={this.viewPhoto} key={item.id}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', height: undefined }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
          );
      }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.items}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          numColumns={3}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()} />}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: state.vault.posts
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchPosts: () => fetchPosts(),
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(VaultScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can add `minWidth` and `maxWidth` styling to the parant View of the render method (in your case give style to `TouchableOpacity` ) value should be `total_width / 3` (+-margin if you want to give) . and then add `width:total_width` to `columnWrapperStyle` of `FlatList`.

NOTE:

-- `total_width = 100%`

-- keeping `minWidth` and `maxWidth` values same will give you perfect view as per your expectation (In your case if `total_width : 100%` then `minWidth` and `maxWidth` values will be `30%`)

Comment: Yes I tried this a while back but issue is in the 1px intended gap between the images. It doesn't distance the images properly

Comment: try adding `alignSelf:'flex-start',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'flex-start'` along with the width inside `columnWrapperStyle` and also try giving `marginHorizontal` for the gaps inside parent view style where  `minWidth` and `maxWidth` styling is given.

this worked for me.

calculate your `total_width` in accordance to the margin given for gaps